# How to secure MongoDB with username and password

Tags: authentication, mongodb

I want to set up user name & password authentication for my MongoDB instance, so that any remote access will ask for the user name & password.  I tried the tutorial from the MongoDB site and did following:

```
use admin
db.addUser('theadmin', '12345');
db.auth('theadmin','12345');
```

After that, I exited and ran mongo again.  And I don't need password to access it. Even if I connect to the database remotely, I am not prompted for user name & password.

---

**UPDATE** Here is the solution I ended up using

```
1) At the mongo command line, set the administrator:

    use admin;
    db.addUser('admin','123456');

2) Shutdown the server and exit

    db.shutdownServer();
    exit

3) Restart mongod with --auth

  $ sudo ./mongodb/bin/mongod --auth --dbpath /mnt/db/

4) Run mongo again in 2 ways:

   i) run mongo first then login:

        $ ./mongodb/bin/mongo localhost:27017
        use admin
        db.auth('admin','123456');

  ii) run & login to mongo in command line.

        $ ./mongodb/bin/mongo localhost:27017/admin -u admin -p 123456
```

The username & password will work the same way for `mongodump` and `mongoexport`.

Comment: this for MongDB version 2.2.x

Comment: In Mongo 3.0.4 the command for creating a user is [db.createUser()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/).

Comment: Please follow this for creating an admin user on Mongodb 3.0 https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/add-user-administrator/

Comment: An update for MongoDB 3.0+: [How to set up authentication in MongoDB 3.0](https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/how-to-setup-auth-in-mongodb-3-0-properly-86b60aeef7e8).

Comment: Just to be clear, this does not encrypt the bytes that pass over the wire. It is only for access control.

Comment: I had to use `service mongod restart` instead of `./mongodb/bin/mongod`.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You need to start `mongod` with the `--auth` option after setting up the user.

From the MongoDB Site:

> Run the database (mongod process) with the `--auth` option to enable
>   security. You must either have added a user to the admin db before
>   starting the server with `--auth`, or add the first user from the
>   localhost interface.

[MongoDB Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/)

Comment: I have tried that and followed the example. now.. i can set it after I restart the server with --auth.  However, when I try to login (./mongo -u theadmin -p 12345 )  I fail.  I can't login.

Comment: If after did that you cannot connect, it's because you are trying to connect on the `admin` db, use another db and try again. Only a userAdmin(AnyDatabase) can connect on `admin`.

Answer (score 140):

**Wow so many complicated/confusing answers here.**

This is as of **v3.4**.

### Short answer.

1. Start MongoDB without access control (`/data/db` or where your db is).

   ```
   mongod --dbpath /data/db
   ```
2. Connect to the instance.

   ```
   mongo
   ```
3. Create the user.

   ```
   use some_db
   db.createUser(
     {
       user: "myNormalUser",
       pwd: "xyz123",
       roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "some_db" },
                { role: "read", db: "some_other_db" } ]
     }
   )
   ```
4. Stop the MongoDB instance and start it again with access control.

   ```
   mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db
   ```
5. Connect and authenticate as the user.

   ```
   use some_db
   db.auth("myNormalUser", "xyz123")
   db.foo.insert({x:1})
   use some_other_db
   db.foo.find({})
   ```

### Long answer: Read this if you want to properly understand.

It's really simple. I'll dumb the following down https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

*If you want to learn more about what the roles actually do read more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/*

1. Start MongoDB without access control.

   ```
   mongod --dbpath /data/db
   ```
2. Connect to the instance.

   ```
   mongo
   ```
3. Create the user administrator. *The following creates a user administrator in the `admin` authentication database. The user is a `dbOwner` over the `some_db` database and NOT over the `admin` database, this is important to remember.*

   ```
   use admin
   db.createUser(
     {
       user: "myDbOwner",
       pwd: "abc123",
       roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "some_db" } ]
     }
   )
   ```

Or if you want to create an admin which is admin over any database:

```
   use admin
   db.createUser(
     {
       user: "myUserAdmin",
       pwd: "abc123",
       roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
     }
   )
```

4. Stop the MongoDB instance and start it again with access control.

   ```
   mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db
   ```
5. Connect and authenticate as the user administrator towards the `admin` authentication database, NOT towards the `some_db` authentication database. *The user administrator was created in the `admin` authentication database, the user does not exist in the `some_db` authentication database.*

   ```
   use admin
   db.auth("myDbOwner", "abc123")
   ```

*You are now authenticated as a `dbOwner` over the `some_db` database. So now if you wish to read/write/do stuff directly towards the `some_db` database you can change to it.*

```
use some_db
//...do stuff like db.foo.insert({x:1})
// remember that the user administrator had dbOwner rights so the user may write/read, if you create a user with userAdmin they will not be able to read/write for example.
```

More on roles: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

*If you wish to make additional users which aren't user administrators and which are just normal users continue reading below.*

6. Create a normal user. *This user will be created in the `some_db` authentication database down below.*

   ```
   use some_db
   db.createUser(
     {
       user: "myNormalUser",
       pwd: "xyz123",
       roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "some_db" },
                { role: "read", db: "some_other_db" } ]
     }
   )
   ```
7. Exit the mongo shell, re-connect, authenticate as the user.

   ```
   use some_db
   db.auth("myNormalUser", "xyz123")
   db.foo.insert({x:1})
   use some_other_db
   db.foo.find({})
   ```

Last but not least due to users not reading the commands I posted correctly regarding the `--auth` flag, you can set this value in the configuration file for mongoDB if you do not wish to set it as a flag.

Comment: Finally I got an idea what is really happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615574/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings-access-control-is-not-enabled-for-the-dat/42926515#42926515

Comment: I find myself wishing accepted answers could get refreshed on SO. This is the most relevant solution as of July 2017.

Comment: **Please update your answer!** I don't know from where you got *userAdminAnyDatabase* from but it doesn't work. The role is *root* for admin access over all the dbs.

Comment: @AakashVerma https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdminAnyDatabase ;) Also NEVER USE ROOT unless for development purposes where you know you cannot be compromised! (tbh just never use root lol)

Comment: I don't understand why you need `/data/db`. The dbpath isn't `dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb` ?

Comment: @John You are correct, dbpath can be whatever you like, aslong as it is pointing towards your db! (in this example I had my db at /data/db)

Comment: Our server just got hacked cause the authentication flag was missing in the config, not on your answer.

Comment: @OliverDixon I'm sorry to hear that. If you look at my answer the `--auth` flag is included when starting the mongoDB process, so I did include it. Yes this flag can also be set in the configuration, whichever one suits your needs.

Comment: And for anyone wondering, if you see `mongosh` in the docs, that because it is the new mongo db shell.

Answer (score 72):

First, un-comment the line that starts with `#auth=true` in your mongod configuration file (default path `/etc/mongod.conf`). This will enable authentication for mongodb.

Then, restart mongodb : `sudo service mongod restart`

Comment: default path is `/etc/mongod.conf` not `/etc/mongo.conf`

Comment: or, firstly uncomment, then restart :)))

Comment: Update: Now restart service with : sudo service mongodb restart

Comment: config file location and name is as: /etc/mongodb.conf

Comment: In the config file its `authorization: enabled` for version 4.4.
See [Mongodb authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) paragraph **4 Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control**

Be also sure to uncomment the `#security:`.

**Example**:

`security:
  authorization: enabled`

Answer (score 57):

This answer is for Mongo 3.2.1
[Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#examples)

**Terminal 1:**

```
$ mongod --auth
```

**Terminal 2:**

```
db.createUser({user:"admin_name", pwd:"1234", roles:["readWrite","dbAdmin"]})
```

if you want to add without roles (optional):

```
db.createUser({user:"admin_name", pwd:"1234", roles:[]})
```

to check if authenticated or not:

```
db.auth("admin_name", "1234")
```

it should give you:

```
1
```

else :

```
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

Comment: older versions such as 2.4 would use db.addUser

Comment: I had to type `use admin` before `createUser` otherwise it gave an error.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a javascript code to add users.

1. Start `mongod` with `--auth = true`
2. Access admin database from mongo shell and pass the javascript file.

   mongo admin "Filename.js"

   "Filename.js"

   ```
   // Adding admin user
   db.addUser("admin_username", " admin_password");
   // Authenticate admin user
   db.auth("admin_username ", " admin_password ");
   // use  database code from java script
   db = db.getSiblingDB("newDatabase");
   // Adding newDatabase database user  
   db.addUser("database_username ", " database_ password ");
   ```
3. Now user addition is complete, we can verify accessing the database from mongo shell

Comment: Setting user name and password in a file does not look very secure.

Comment: Javascript. Not "java script".

Comment: what is the purpose of javascript file here ?

Comment: @CamiloMartin JavaScript, not "Javascript".

Answer (score 28):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization

Edit the mongo settings file;

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

Add the line:

```
security.authorization : enabled
```

Restart the service

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Regards

Comment: I don't understand why everybody don't mention this. It's so important

Comment: Probably the most important answer. Our server got hacked cause the other answers didn't mention this.

Answer (score 14):

You could change `/etc/mongod.conf`.

Before

`#security:`

After

```
security:
    authorization: "enabled"
```

Then `sudo service mongod restart`

Answer (score 12):

First run mongoDB on terminal using

```
mongod
```

now run mongo shell use following commands

```
    use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control.

```
mongod --auth
```

Now authenticate yourself from the command line using

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

I read it from

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: i defined a user, with root, then add more and more till i find you, `MongoDB Enterprise > db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : "admin.admin", "user" : "admin", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "SC
RAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000, "salt" : "k96PCEflidMY5seVju+gAw==", "s
toredKey" : "CabQTnJtny7cv0wT5X8oX9QOn3A=", "serverKey" : "RJyCdnlIhyIfj2+d44L61
bYK+MU=" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase", "db" : "admin" }, {
 "role" : "dbAdmin", "db" : "admin" }, { "role" : "userAdmin", "db" : "admin" },
 { "role" : "root", "db" : "admin" } ] }` still authentication fails

Comment: i even used db.changeUserPassword(), or any thing it was, even after that, when i call db.auth('admin', 'my pass') or the way you done it, it says authentication failed for user admin

Comment: Use `root` role to provides access to the operations and all the resources of the following roles combined... [role root](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#root)

Answer (score 11):

This is what I did on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ sudo apt install mongodb
$ mongo
> show dbs
> use admin
> db.createUser({  user: "root",  pwd: "rootpw",  roles: [ "root" ]  })  // root user can do anything
> use lefa
> db.lefa.save( {name:"test"} )
> db.lefa.find()
> show dbs
> db.createUser({  user: "lefa",  pwd: "lefapw",  roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "lefa" } ]  }) // admin of a db
> exit
$ sudo vim /etc/mongodb.conf
auth = true
$ sudo systemctl restart mongodb
$ mongo -u "root" -p "rootpw" --authenticationDatabase  "admin"
> use admin
> exit
$ mongo -u "lefa" -p "lefapw" --authenticationDatabase  "lefa"
> use lefa
> exit
```

Answer (score 6):

**User creation with password for a specific database to secure database access :**

```
use dbName

db.createUser(
   {
     user: "dbUser",
     pwd: "dbPassword",
     roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
   }
)
```

Answer (score 6):

## mongodb 4.4.13 community

### 1. create database user

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

#### 1.2 verify working

```
> db.auth('myUserAdmin','abc123')

< { ok: 1 }
```

if it fails you get

```
> db.auth('myUserAdmin','amongus')

MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
```

### 2. modify /etc/mongod.conf

```
nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

change:

```
#security:
```

to:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

### 3. restart mongod service

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

### Follow the below steps in order

- Create a user using the CLI

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "admin123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

- Enable authentication, how you do it differs based on your OS, if you are using windows you can simply `mongod --auth` in case of linux you can edit the `/etc/mongod.conf` file to add `security.authorization : enabled` and then restart the mongd service
- To connect via cli `mongo -u "admin" -p "admin123" --authenticationDatabase  "admin"`. That's it

You can check out [this post](https://ciphertrick.com/2019/03/01/setup-mongodb-authentication-connect-using-mongoose/) to go into more details and to learn connecting to it using mongoose.

Answer (score 4):

The best practice to connect to mongoDB as follow:

1. After initial installation,

   `use admin`
2. Then run the following script to create admin user

```
    db.createUser(
     {
         user: "YourUserName",
         pwd: "YourPassword",
         roles: [
                   { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
                   { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
                   { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
                   { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }
                ]
     })
```

the following script will create the admin user for the DB.

3. log into the `db.admin` using

   `mongo -u YourUserName -p YourPassword admin`
4. After login, you can create N number of the database with same admin credential or different by repeating the 1 to 3.

This allows you to create different user and password for the different collection you creating in the MongoDB

Comment: after this go to sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf and put this line security.authorization: enabled, you can see the reference link here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57384027/3904109

Answer (score 4):

This is what i did for ubuntu 20.04 and mongodb enterprise 4.4.2:

1. start mongo shell by typing `mongo` in terminal.
2. use admin database:

```
use admin
```

3. create a new user and assign your intended role:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

4. exit mongo and add the following line to `etc/mongod.conf`:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

5. restart mongodb server

(optional) 6.If you want your user to have root access you can either specify it when creating your user like:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

or you can change user role using:

```
db.grantRolesToUser('admin', [{ role: 'root', db: 'admin' }])
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of the answers are sending mixed signals between using `--auth` command line flag or setting config file property.

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I would like to clarify that aspect. First of all,  authentication credentials (ie user/password) in both cases has to be created by executing `db.createUser` query on the default `admin` database. Once credentials are obtained, there are two ways to enable authentication:

1. Without a custom config file: This is when the former `auth` flag is applicable. Start `mongod` like: `usr/bin/mongod --auth`
2. With a custom config file: This is when the latter configs has to be present in the custom config file.Start `mongod` like: `usr/bin/mongod --config <config file path>`

To connect to the mongo shell with authentication:
`mongo -u <user> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase admin`

`--authenticationDatabase` here is the database name where the user was created. All other mongo commands like `mongorestore`, `mongodump`  accept the additional options ie  `-u <user> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase admin`

Refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/ for details.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to switch to the database you want the user on (not the admin db) ...

`use mydatabase`

See this post for more help ... https://web.archive.org/web/20140316031938/http://learnmongo.com/posts/quick-tip-mongodb-users/

Comment: don't need because setting db = db.getSiblingDB("newDatabase");

Comment: I cannot imagine any reason why users should be created in other database than `admin`

Answer (score 3):

These steps worked on me:

1. write mongod --port 27017 on cmd
2. then connect to mongo shell : mongo --port 27017
3. create the user admin : 
   use admin
   db.createUser(
   {
   user: "myUserAdmin",
   pwd: "abc123",
   roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
   }
   )
4. disconnect mongo shell
5. restart the mongodb : mongod --auth --port 27017
6. start mongo shell :
   mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
7. To authenticate after connecting, Connect the mongo shell to the mongod:
   mongo --port 27017
8. switch to the authentication database :
   use admin
   db.auth("myUserAdmin", "abc123"

Answer (score 2):

after you create new user, please don't forget to `grant` `read/write/root` permission to the user. you can try the

`cmd: db.grantRolesToUser('yourNewUsername',[{ role: "root", db: "admin" }])`

Answer (score 1):

Many duplicate answers but I think they miss an important note:

**Even when authentication is enabled properly you can connect to the Mongo database without username/password!**

However, you can execute only harmless commands like `db.help()`, `db.getMongo()`, `db.listCommands()`, etc.

```
$ mongo 
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("f662858b-8658-4e33-a735-120e3639c131") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.3
mongos> db.getMongo()
connection to 127.0.0.1:27017
mongos> db
test
mongos> db.version()
4.4.3
mongos> db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})
{
        "authInfo" : {
                "authenticatedUsers" : [ ],
                "authenticatedUserRoles" : [ ]
        },
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1618996970, 2),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1618996970, 2),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"Kre9jvnJvsW+OVCl1QC+eKSBbbY="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6944343118355365892")
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in version 6.0
how to set user name and password for a database;

install MongoDB 6.0 or higher
create database(whatever the name may be) in MongoDB using compass

[image]
install MongoDB Shell
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell

open cmd

> cd C:\Program Files\mongosh

> mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017"

> use #your database name#

> db.createUser(   {     user: "xxx",    pwd: "xxx",    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "xxx" } ]  } )

[image]