# How do I change a MongoDB user's password?

Tags: mongodb

I used db.addUser(...) to create a user at some point in the past.  How do I now change that user's password?

I logged in with a user with userAdmin role.  What command do I use to change another user's password?

**Edit 2**

I need this answered for the v2.4 style addUser and privilege documents

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-documents/

**Edit**

It has been suggested that I use the 2.2 addUser syntax to change the password.  This does not work:

```
db.addUser({user: "test", pwd: "oldPassword", roles: ["readWrite"]})
db.addUser("test", "newPassword")
```

gives

```
uncaught exception: couldn't add user: system.users entry must not have both 'roles' and 'readOnly' fields
```

Comment: Remove and readd the user

Comment: @Sammaye Is this really the only way?

Comment: I believe it is in some cases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
db.changeUserPassword("test", "newPassword")
```

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/KkXbDCsCfOs/rk2_h-oSbAwJ
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-1515

Finally found it!

Answer (score 1):

To change a password, just run the `addUser` command again.

```
db.addUser("coolguy",  "newxH@x0rPasswd", true);
```

Comment: This is the old style addUser.  I am using the new style user docs.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-documents/

Comment: db.addUser({user: "super", pwd: "123456"})   GIVES   'roles' field must be provided src/mongo/shell/db.js:155

Comment: db.addUser({user: "super", pwd: "123456", roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "clusterAdmin"]}) GIVES uncaught exception: User already exists with that username/userSource combination

Comment: db.addUser("super", "123456") GIVES uncaught exception: couldn't add user: system.users entry must not have both 'roles' and 'readOnly' fields

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302417/changing-the-password-in-mongodb-for-exsisting-user) might help.

Becareful about the argument passed. That is for readOnly option.

EDIT : 
Steps I followed in : Added a new user

```
> db.addUser("admin","firstpwd") 
{
    "user" : "admin",
    "readOnly" : false,
    "pwd" : "40a84fcba954c8924d277f23b0f880b1",
    "_id" : ObjectId("51966ec8c7ad876ba0319438")
}
```

exit

```
> db.auth("admin","firstpwd")
1
```

Changing the password

```
> db.addUser("admin","secondpwd")
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51966ec8c7ad876ba0319438"),
    "user" : "admin",
    "readOnly" : false,
    "pwd" : "82f4e416844349418281a3eca1cf6082"
}
```

exit

> db.auth("admin","secondpwd")
>   1

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3

Comment: I saw that but the answer is speaking to the asker's confusion about the --auth command line option.  I just want to change a user's password.

Comment: just use the db.addUser() again with the new password

Comment: I tried this but it gives "uncaught exception: User already exists with that username/userSource combination"

Comment: Here is the output

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
> db.addUser("coolguy",  "hereIsoldpwd")
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("51966b49ef4f47402f6be04c"),
 "user" : "coolguy",
 "readOnly" : false,
 "pwd" : "4f9a89c83b9493f5666762ed0149f258"
}

I exit from DB , logged in again,

> db.auth("coolguy",  "hereIsoldpwd")
1
> db.addUser("coolguy",  "hereisNewPwd")
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("51966b49ef4f47402f6be04c"),
 "user" : "coolguy",
 "readOnly" : false,
 "pwd" : "4f9a89c83b9493f5666762ed0149f258"
}
It worked pretty well for me

Comment: I see you are using the old style user privilege docs.  I am using the 2.4 style docs with roles. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-documents/ and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/