# mongoose and mongodb authentication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create one GOD user who has access to all the dbs

The following users have been created :

```
db.createUser( { user: "admin", pwd: "password", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ]    })
db.createUser( { user: "root", pwd: "password", roles: [ "root" ]    })
db.createUser( { user: "mongo", pwd: "password", roles: [  "readWriteAnyDatabase","dbAdminAnyDatabase","clusterAdmin" ]})
```

I am trying to connect through the following connection URL

`mongodb://mongo:password@<mongodb IP>/development_admin`

I tried with all the users created but none seemed to work. I always get the following error :

```
   MongoError: auth failed
```

Is there anything that I am performing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you show the code that is doing the connection and authentication? Can you connect through the mongo shell ok? `$ mongo -u admin -p password --host mymongohost:mymongoport/mymongodatabase`

Comment: Yes, I could connect using mongoshell

Comment: [Authentication is managed at a database level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216712/cannot-authenticate-into-mongo-auth-fails)

Comment: @laggingreflex: not necessarily. Basically, you can use every database to store the auth info – though you have to change explicitly state [`authenticationDatabase`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption--authenticationDatabase) then.