# Mongo server accepts credentials from shell, but not from Java/Scala interface

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working on a Scala framework that wants to connect to a local MongoDB instance using the Mongo Java library, but fails.  The URI it uses to connect is:

```
mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/mydb
```

This causes the following exception to be raised when I try to update a collection:

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}
```

However, if I extract the parameters from the URI and give them to the Mongo shell:

```
$ mongo -u user -p pass --host localhost --port 27017 mydb
```

...then it lets me in!  Can anyone suggest why this might be?

Possibly but unlikely to be relevant:  Everything was working fine in the original environment I ran my framework in, a Dell laptop running Ubuntu.  Now I'm trying to run it on a Mac laptop running Ubuntu in Virtualbox.  Everything should be virtually (ha) identical, but obviously isn't somehow.

Comment: I'd check if your server accept remote connections, also if your shell uses a different jdk than your java application or if your firewall (iptables perhaps) are bothering

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216712/cannot-authenticate-into-mongo-auth-fails ?

Comment: @user3707125 That question seems to deal with authenticating as an admin on an existing connection versus making a new connection.  In my case I'm getting conflicting responses with two different ways of making a new connection (shell vs. API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a version mismatch, apparently.  I tried uninstalling the 3.0.3 that Ubuntu provided and used 2.6.10 which I downloaded from mongodb.org, and my library was finally able to connect.

This was after I spotted a line in the log which from memory was something like "credentials not found in user document."

Man, I know some breakage might be expected when crossing a major version number, but preventing older clients from even being able to connect at all seems pretty extreme.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to upgrade my mongo driver from `v2.12.5` to `v2.13.0` to get it work.