# MongoDB+Java: Credentials missing in the user document

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication, database

Testing of MongoDB connection fails in Java with correct login credentials for an existing database. A `com.mongodb.CommandFailureException` is displayed.

This can be a mismatch between different versions of MongoDB, because I'm using code that was written for version **2.6** and running it with version **3**. It's less likely to be between different versions of MongoDB driver, because I'm using a the same version (`mongo-java-driver 2.12.4`) that the code was tested on.

What can I do to fix this error and make it compatible with a range of MongoDB versions?

```
String dbName = "test_db";
String host = "localhost";
Integer port = 27017;
String username = "admin";
String password = "password";

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MongoTest.class.getName());

log.debug("DBNAME:"+dbName+"\nHOST:"+host+"\nPORT:"+port+"\nUSERNAME:"+username+"\nPASSWORD:"+password+"\n");

MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(username, dbName, password.toCharArray());
List<MongoCredential> auths = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
        auths.add(credential);

MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), auths);
DB db = mongo.getDB(dbName);
log.debug("DB:"+db); // not null
DBCollection dbCollection = db.createCollection("__test__", new BasicDBObject()); // FAIL
```

`mongo.log`:

```
2015-12-04T15:55:36.148+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:7273 #79 (18 connections now open)
2015-12-04T15:55:36.242+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:7274 #80 (19 connections now open)
2015-12-04T15:55:36.256+0100 I ACCESS   [conn80]  authenticate db: test_db { authenticate: 1, user: "admin", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-12-04T15:55:36.258+0100 I ACCESS   [conn80] Failed to authenticate admin@test_db with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-12-04T15:55:36.265+0100 I NETWORK  [conn80] end connection 127.0.0.1:7274 (18 connections now open)
2015-12-04T15:55:36.282+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:7275 #81 (19 connections now open)
2015-12-04T15:55:36.301+0100 I NETWORK  [conn79] end connection 127.0.0.1:7273 (18 connections now open)
2015-12-04T15:55:36.301+0100 I NETWORK  [conn81] end connection 127.0.0.1:7275 (18 connections now open)
```

The exception:

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$NativeAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:652)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.authenticate(DBPort.java:364)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:375)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.doOperation(DBTCPConnector.java:209)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.sendWriteCommandMessage(DBCollectionImpl.java:477)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.writeWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:427)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:387)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:186)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:165)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:120)
    at com.scs.setup.webapp.util.Mongo.isConnectionValid(Mongo.java:39)
    at com.scs.setup.webapp.controller.AjaxActionTest.isMongoConnectionValidDefault(AjaxActionTest.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: have you checked with version of Mongo ?

Comment: i'm still looking in manual for version 3 of MongoDB what query actually gets called

Comment: well these 2 links says similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793784/mongo-server-accepts-credentials-from-shell-but-not-from-java-scala-interface
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216712/cannot-authenticate-into-mongo-auth-fails

Comment: they are probably asking the same, but a good solution with Java code was not proposed yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by properly adding the user in Mongo (3.0.7) CLI, I tried running it on `admin` database, while it should have been on `test_db` database:

```
mongo --authenticationDatabase db_name -u username -p password
(Connected to Mongo CLI client...)
> use test-db;
> db.createUser( 
  { 
    "user" : "admin", 
    "pwd": "password",  
    "roles" : [      
      { role: "root", db: "admin" },
      { role: "readWrite", db: "admin" }, 
      { role: "dbAdmin", db: "admin" },
      { role: "readWrite", db: "test_db" }, 
      { role: "dbAdmin", db: "test_db" }
    ]  
});
(Success...)
> db.auth("admin","password")
1
```