# Authenticate After Picking the Database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have 3 databases in my MongoDB server. I am using pymongo to do some scripting with Python3.

I want to use the latest versions and practices. Once I open the client and pick the database, the API for pymongo.MongoClient.['mydatabase'].authenticate is deprecated.
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html

Authentication prior to picking the database (while dialing the client) doesn't seem to flow down toward the database. Not just for pymongo, but also when I use mongo shell. So I have a feeling this is the issue.

script.py

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
u = getUser()         # function which prompts for username
p = getPassword()     # getpass.getpass('Password')
uri = formatUri(u, p) # formats 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s'.format(user, password, host)

client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client['mydb']
col = db.mycollection
for doc in col.find():
    print(doc)
```

I get the error that I am not authorized for the database. I know my account works in shell but I have to dial the client first then use the db and then auth.

Here's a mongo shell example:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: v3.4.10
Connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:port
MongoDB server version: v3.4.10
> use mydb
switched to mydb
> db.auth("user", "pass")
1
```

Any idea how I can either auth after picking the database or once I use the db it remembers the context I dialed with?

Comment: The intent is that ALL authentication is stored in `"admin"` and simply identifies which database namespaces the account has the available privileges. So you would assign privelages on to the user for `"mydb"`, but there is no such requirement that you "log in" on that database alone. It simply means that if you switch to `"foo"` database namespace where there are no assigned privileges, then you "cannot do anything". If you had privileges for "both" database namespaces, then you are allowed access to things without the need to "authenticate" again. Is that somewhat clearer?

Comment: I initially thought that was how it worked. For example, without using a database, I created my mongo user with all privileges in admin with literally every possible access and another user with just read access. I would then auth (still in admin) with that main account. Then switch and use "mydb" and when I "show users" in mydb, nothing shows. So I thought I had to recreate the account in mydb and give access.

Comment: It does. It makes sense to me because that is how I expected it to work the first time and I realized I created separate users within the same database. However, when I try to create a new user in `admin` I still can't use d.auth() to login in the database I am using. (I'm using just shell at this point since I realized it was never pymongo that had the issue). I believe I may have to reinstall mongo and start clean since I keep messing with the users, config, etc.

Comment: This is what you are being prompted to do, as your account has a low reputation and no accepted answers since 2015. So this is a "reminder" that you have left this unattended, and where the question you asked is given an acceptable answer, you mark it as such.

Comment: It still doesn't print the user I created in admin however when I am using a new database.

Comment: How do I raise my reputation? I don't see that in the pymongo API exactly.

Comment: Follow the steps in the answer provided. It's meant to show you step by step how to do authentication properly. If you have questions, then please comment on the "answer" like you were asked. But I provided the answer so you follow the steps and learn. You seem to be indicating you have not done that.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing some concepts here so I'll basically answer as a "guide" to what you should be doing instead. So "authentication' is not really something you do "after" connection, but rather you need to be "looking in the right place" when you actually attempt to authenticate.

We can start this by essentially following the process outlined in [Enable Auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) from the core documentation, but specifically altered because you want to be running this "test" under your own user account and local directory.

### Revision Steps - Straight from Documentation

So first would would want to pick a local working directory and make a path for the database storage files underneath that. On *nix based systems you can do something like:

```
mkdir -p scratch/data/db
cd scratch
```

Then we want to startup a separate MongoDB instance without any other options. Making sure the port does not conflict with any other running instance:

```
mongod --port 37017 --dbpath data/db
```

In a new terminal or command line window, you can then connect to the shell:

```
mongo --port 37017
```

You always want at least one account with administrative privileges to at least "create accounts" and alter them in case you get in trouble, so create one:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "admin",
    roles: [{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }]
  }
)
```

Now exit the shell and close the existing `mongod` instance running in the other terminal or command prompt and then start it again using `--auth`:

```
mongod --auth --port 37017 --dbpath data/db
```

### Specific User - Make sure you follow these

Now you actually want to create a user that will be "used by your application". So these steps are important to ensure you get it right.

Log into a shell using your "adminstrative user":

```
mongo -u admin -p admin --port 37017 --authenticationDatabase 'admin'
```

You can alternately do the `db.auth()` method as shown in the question, but as noted this **must** be authorised on the `"admin"` namespace.

The next thing you want to do is create a user with access to `"mydb"` as a namespace with the `readWrite` role. For kicks, we are also going to let this user have the `readAnyDatabase` allowing them to "list" all databases namespaces, if not actually being able to do anything else with them.

> **IMPORTANT**: You create ALL your users in the `"admin"` namespace. And this will be very important in future releases:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    "user": "myuser",
    "pwd": "password",
    "roles": [
      { "role": "readWrite", "db": "mydb" },
      "readAnyDatabase"
    ]
  }
)
```

Just for additional output, let's look at the current created users:

```
db.getUsers()
[
        {
                "_id" : "admin.admin",
                "user" : "admin",
                "db" : "admin",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        }
                ]
        },
        {
                "_id" : "admin.myuser",
                "user" : "myuser",
                "db" : "admin",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "readWrite",
                                "db" : "mydb"
                        },
                        {
                                "role" : "readAnyDatabase",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        }
                ]
        }
]
```

See how these have expanded in naming, and particularly the values assigned to the various `"db"` keys on each user. This should give you a little more insight into how MongoDB looks this up and why.

### Python Connection

Finally we just want to connect from python. So presuming you have python and pymongo installed already, then it's just a simple listing to verify:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://myuser:password@localhost:37017');

db = client['mydb']
col = db.test

col.remove()

col.insert_one({ "a": 1 })

for doc in col.find():
  print(doc)
```

Which shows the document created and listed without problem:

```
{u'a': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('5a08e5e0760108251722a737')}
```

Note that we don't actually need to make any mention of `"admin"` here, because this is the default where the driver "expects the accounts to be" and where you really "should" be doing it.

### But I did it the wrong way

So let's say you originally got all confused and created the user under `"mydb"` instead:

```
use mydb
db.createUser({ "user": "bert", "pwd": "password", "roles": ["readWrite"] })
```

If you go look in `"admin"` that user is not there. But if you look on `"mydb"`:

```
use mydb
db.getUsers()
[
        {
                "_id" : "mydb.bert",
                "user" : "bert",
                "db" : "mydb",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "readWrite",
                                "db" : "mydb"
                        }
                ]
        }
]
```

So you can see where the actual user data is now kept and how it has been recorded.

The simple case here is you "must" tell MongoDB where to obtain the authentication from for this user:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://bert:password@localhost:37017/mydb');
```

See how we add `"mydb"` on to the connection string. This is how it's done.

---

This is actually "in progress" to be made consistent with ALL drivers in how connections are made and where authentication happens as well as where you select the database. But there are basic rules:

1. If no other database namespace is provided with connection details for authentication credentials, then `"admin"` is taken to be the **default**.
2. Where there is a database namespace provided on the connection string, **this will be used for authentication** and this is the actual intent of the database namespace on the connection string.
3. Though other drivers "presently" differ in the role of the database namespace on the connection string, the usage is being changed to be consistent with all drivers that "using" a database namespace is in fact an API call, rather than being assigned from the connection string.

So where you need to authenticate depends on "where you created the user". But you should really be noting that `"admin"` is the place where you "should" be doing this instead of anywhere else.

> #### Deprecation of Authenticate after connect
>
> Whilst all drivers actually do have a similar method to [`authenticate()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate), which is used much like the shell example in the question, this method is now considered **DEPRECATED** as is mentioned throughout the content of the answer it is "intended" that you actually store your users in the `"admin"` namespace:
>
> *"Changed in version 3.5: Deprecated. Authenticating multiple users conflicts with support for logical sessions in MongoDB 3.6. To authenticate as multiple users, create multiple instances of MongoClient."*
>
> This is why the whole answer here is based on **NOT** using that method as you are meant to creating new connection instances, or using the "sessions" functionality available from MongoDB 3.6 instead.