# MongoError: Authentication failed. NestJs MongoDb Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, mongodb-atlas

I've build a nest.js server and now I'm trying to connect mongoDB Atlas.
In the app.module imports i've tried to connect with

> mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@cluster0.iijhz.mongodb.net/<dbName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority

url string, but failed, now i've tried these options too:

```
imports: [
MongooseModule.forRoot(
  'mongodb+srv://cluster0.iijhz.mongodb.net',
  {
    user: '<user>',
    pass: '<pass>',
    dbName: '<dbName>',
    w: 'majority',
    retryWrites: true
  }
),
```

but still got

> MongoError: Authentication failed.

my ip, and 0.0.0.0/0 is also added to whitelist.

Comment: Probably this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20809536/4980141

Comment: Thanks, i've read the docs, and some articles about nest's MongooseModule, then read the docs for MongoDB Atlas, changed my password several times, and just after that all, checked the name of the db, which was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, surely my bad, the `dbName` wasn't correct the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I faced was not whitelisting my IP address. The error was not visible when tried with NestJS but while using it with express I found out the error!

In case you're wondering how to change IP address in MongoDB atlas:

> 1. Goto MongoDB atlas dashboard
> 2. Select Network Access option under Security
> 3. In the IP address tab, clik edit on the first(according to your requirement) IP address.
> 4. Click Add Current IP address(for only your current IP, you can't access from other IP) / select "Global IP" or 0.0.0.0/0 for getting
>    access from anywhere.
> 5. It should work now!

Hope that helps!