# can't set authentication on mongodb in windows 8

Tags: mongodb, authentication

i'm trying to set authentication on mongodb in my windows 8

i want to do the same steps as this address
[How to secure MongoDB with username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881208/how-to-put-username-password-in-mongodb)

this is want i have done

`>mongod -auth`

open another cmd

`>mongo`

`>use admin`

after this, i want to type `db.addUser()` but there's no such function... 
only `db.adminCommand()` and `db.auth()`

how can i do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i find the reason...
cuz my mongodb is 3.0.3...there's no function called addUser()

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/