# MongoDB status failed after editing mongo.conf (code-exited, status=2)

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect remotely to my Google Cloud Server with [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) to connect too [MongoDB v4.0.11](https://www.mongodb.com/) just so I can see the data from windows.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04LTS Minimal. To enable remote connections to MongoDB I have first created both an administrative and root user in my admin database.

My problem is once I add `authorization: "enabled"` to `security:` in `/etc/mongod.conf` and restart MongoDB, I get the following status when running `$:systemctl status mongod`

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-08-06 16:43:51 BST; 1min 20s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 6517 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 6517 (code=exited, status=2)

Aug 06 16:43:51 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Aug 06 16:43:51 instance-1 mongod[6517]: Unrecognized option: processManagement.authorization
Aug 06 16:43:51 instance-1 mongod[6517]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
Aug 06 16:43:51 instance-1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Aug 06 16:43:51 instance-1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Example of `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
# mongod.conf
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
  authorization: "enabled"
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

It appears there is an invalid argument in `/etc/mongod.conf` but from what I have read online I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the 4.x release it appears you need to modify the existing security section you have listed

```
#security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

And replace it with `security.authorization: enabled` or

```
security:
      authorization: "enabled"
```

You should then be able to reload and test authentication is working as expected.

If you dig into the docs you will find the relevant section [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization).

> security.authorization
>
> ```
> Type: string
>
> Default: disabled
>
> Enable or disable Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) to govern each user’s access to database resources and operations.
>
> Set this option to one of the following:
> Value     Description
> enabled   A user can access only the database resources and actions for which they have been granted privileges.
> disabled  A user can access any database and perform any action.
> ```

Comment: you can change the security settings at sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: for versions 4 and up it is security.authorization: enabled

Answer (score 12):

wrong:

```
#security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

correct:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that I used a tab to indent the `authorization: enabled` line. When I replaced the tab with 2 spaces it worked.

Comment: Thank you. that's exactly what was wrong for me

Comment: The same issue i had. I lost my 1 hour for my tab