# Mongodb Status failed after editing .conf file

Tags: mongodb

I want to enable the security by using creating a user in `admin` db. And I created that user after that I will edit mongodb conf file. After that I'm facing some issue while connecting that I'm not able to connect with the shell. After google I reached to a question with accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380491/mongodb-status-failed-after-editing-mongo-conf-code-exited-status-2). I follow that question and did all the things given in the answer then still facing issue while connecting with mongo shell. I'm pasting mongo conf file. Please let me know if there is any changes.

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
  security.authorization: enabled
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

Should be fine. And don't forget to restart the server.