# How to secure MongoDB? I have been hacked

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I do not use MongoDB before, after set everything up, my mongoDB has been hacked for 1 second, please help me answer my question: "how to secure my mongoDB?"

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to secure MongoDB with username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881208/how-to-secure-mongodb-with-username-and-password)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Secure MongoDB you need to :

- enable security (in mongod.conf file),
- create database user for authentication ,
- you can change port 27001 (default) to any port like 27000 (in mongod.conf file)
- you can add specific ip address to allow to connect and access your database (in mongod.conf file).

you need to find out **mongod.conf** and open it . (google it out where is mongod.conf is stored in your pc windows/mac/ubuntu)

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Shutdown the MongoDB instance on port 27001

```
mongo admin --port 27001 --eval 'db.shutdownServer()'
```

Restart the MongoDB instance with the new configuration

```
mongod -f mongod.conf
```

Create the first user on the **admin** database with the following

```
mongo
>use admin

db.createUser({
  user: "USER_NAME_HERE",
  pwd: "PASSWORD_HERE",
  roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
});
```

example :

```
db.createUser({
  user: "AdminUser",
  pwd: "57d49$4%0beqwe#adb4d",
  roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
});
```

after that run following to check user is authenticated

Syntax :    **db.auth( "USER_NAME_HERE", "PASSWORD_HERE" )**

```
db.auth( "AdminUser", "57d49$4%0beqwe#adb4d" )
```

To Check Users :

```
db.getUsers()
```

It will return :

```
[
        {
                "_id" : "admin.AdminUser",
                "userId" : UUID("31ccb892-d3ef-46b6-8ac1-2e9b5be11892"),
                "user" : "globalAdminUser",
                "db" : "admin",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        }
                ],
                "mechanisms" : [
                        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
                ]
        }
]
```

Now your database is secured and only authenticated user can access it .

you can connect mongo with folowing :

```
mongo admin --port 27001 --username 'AdminUser' --password '57d49$4%0beqwe#adb4d'
```

Comment: Thank you much, this is my very first time using MongoDB!